# Use of MKL libraries in Visual Studio

Tags: fortran, intel-mkl

I need to use the Fortran function "vsCdfNormInv", contained in the library 'mkl_vml.f90' (C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2015\mkl\include). I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. How may I include the libraries by a command contained in the code? I solved the problem adding the additional dependencies to the linker: "mkl_intel_c.lib mkl_intel_thread.lib mkl_core.lib libiomp5md.lib", so the following code works.

```
program Console1
implicit none
REAL , DIMENSION (1:15) :: ESTRAZIONIUNIFORMI,ESTRAZIONIGAUSSIANE
CALL RANDOM_NUMBER (ESTRAZIONIUNIFORMI)
CALL vsCdfNormInv(15,ESTRAZIONIUNIFORMI,ESTRAZIONIGAUSSIANE)
end program Console1
```

but, using the same command in a subroutine I get a wrong vector of "ESTRAZIONIGAUSSIANE". Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you get, and what did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Intel® Math Kernel Library Link Line Advisor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor) to help you generate the correct linking options required by the compiler. At least what you have linked seems not enough.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if missing libraries caused wrong results unless he used long integers or similar strange option.